# Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to read data from response and set it in my HTML.But it is giving me undefined error. Can anyone help what am I doing wrong here.

Following is snippet of component:

```
userProfile: any
constructor(private _userProfileService: UserProfileService ){}

ngOnInit(){
this._userProfileService.getProfileData()
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log("Response");
    console.log(data);
            this.userProfile = data;
            console.log(this.userProfile.user.firstname);
        });
```

}

the HTML:

```
<h2>{{userProfile.user.firstname}} {{userProfile.user.lastname}}'s Profile <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/pen.png" alt="pen"></a></h2>
```

Comment: Fixed with this line:   userProfile: any = {};

Comment: only one question why didn't you accepted my answer as it was the first ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi  First of all thank you for your answer, it solved my problem.I didn't check who has posted the answer at which millisecond and as far as I understand this community is to help developers solve issues and not fight over trivial matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use safe operator

```
<div *ngIf='userProfile?.user'>
<h2>{{userProfile.user.firstname}} {{userProfile.user.lastname}}'s Profile <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/pen.png" alt="pen"></a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue :

Because you are trying to display data before its available to the view.

Try this :

```
<div *ngIf='userProfile?.user'>
<h2>{{userProfile.user.firstname}} {{userProfile.user.lastname}}'s Profile <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/pen.png" alt="pen"></a></h2>
</div>
```